# Wordpress Footer Issue (Random text showing up)

Tags: wordpress

Okay all of a sudden this morning when I woke up to look at this wordpress I've been working on this appeared in the footer of my wordpress. It is causing each page to reproduce itself multiple times. Anyone know what this could be?

**Start function wbga_insert_html_once: head, Footer hooked: HTML inserted: Location is HEAD Start function wbga_get_option: footer_hooked wbga_options: array ( 'internal_domains' => 'beta.fundly.com', 'account_id' => 'UA-18454942-1', 'enable_tracker' => true, 'track_adm_pages' => false, 'ignore_users' => true, 'max_user_level' => '8', 'footer_hooked' => false, 'filter_content' => true, 'filter_comments' => true, 'filter_comment_authors' => true, 'track_ext_links' => true, 'prefix_ext_links' => '/out/', 'track_files' => true, 'prefix_file_links' => '/download/', 'track_extensions' => 'gif,jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,pdf,mp3,wav,phps,zip,gz,tar,rar,jar,exe,pps,ppt,xls,doc', 'track_mail_links' => true, 'prefix_mail_links' => '/mailto/', 'debug' => true, 'advanced_config' => false, 'tracking_type' => '1', 'fb_cam_tracking' => false, ) Ending function wbga_get_option: footer_hooked () Inserting HTML since footer is not hooked End function wbga_insert_html Ending function wbga_wp_head_track: Start function wbga_filter:**

Link to the issue: http://beta.fundly.com/features

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the Web Ninja Google Analytics plugin that you're using. If you have a home.php or a front-page.php, could you please comment with a link to a pastebin with the code inside? If you don't have a home.php or a front-page.php, please comment with a link to a pastebin with your index.php and footer.php content.

Comment: Did you get my comment from above?

Comment: OK, could you pastebin footer.php now? I'm thinking that the plugin is finding something wrong with the footer that is preventing it from working correctly; possibly a missing wp_footer() call in footer.php, but not sure.